# Why is the mass dimension of the covariant derivative 1?

Tags: general-relativity, differentiation, dimensional-analysis, absolute-units

I'm reviewing an exam, and I can't figure this one out. I know the covariant derivative, but I'm not seeing how it necessarily has a mass dimension.

Answer (score 3):

A spatial (temporal) covariant derivative $\nabla_{\mu}$ has dimension $[\nabla_{\mu}]$ of inverse length (time), respectively. In [natural units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units) where $\hbar=1=c$, that is also dimension of mass.

Comment: However, in geometric units ($G=c=1$) units of inverse length would be inverse mass as well. I guess this depends on the context of the question.

Comment: Dang it. It's one of those things that in retrospect is obvious. Thanks @Qmechanic

Comment: @mmeent: Right. Moreover, in Planck units $c=\hbar=G=1$, length, time and mass are all dimensionless.